# Fake obfuscation of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to fake an obfuscation like the code below:

```
var _0xa338=["\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x6A\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x2D\x31\x2E\x33\x2E\x32\x2E\x6D\x69\x6E\x2E\x6A\x73\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65","\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x6A\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x2E\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65\x2E\x6A\x73\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x6A\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x2E\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x2E\x6A\x73\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x2E\x6A\x73\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x3C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x73\x73\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x22\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x63\x73\x73\x22\x20\x2F\x3E","\x20\x20\x3C\x21\x2D\x2D\x5B\x69\x66\x20\x6C\x74\x20\x49\x45\x20\x37\x5D\x3E\x20\x3C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x64\x61\x6D\x6E\x69\x65\x36\x2E\x63\x73\x73\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x22\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x63\x73\x73\x22\x20\x2F\x3E\x20\x3C\x21\x5B\x65\x6E\x64\x69\x66\x5D\x2D\x2D\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x63\x68\x61\x74\x62\x6F\x78\x22\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x3A\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65\x22\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x22\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2F\x66\x63\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x66\x2E\x67\x69\x66\x22\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3D\x22\x31\x38\x22\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3D\x22\x32\x33\x22\x20\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6E\x69\x63\x6B\x22\x3E","\x20\x20\x3C\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x6E\x69\x63\x6B\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x22\x20\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x22\x6E\x69\x63\x6B\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x22\x20\x6D\x65\x74\x68\x6F\x64\x3D\x22\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x22\x20\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3D\x22\x22\x20\x6F\x6E\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x3D\x22\x64\x6F\x4C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x28\x29\x3B\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x66\x61\x6C\x73\x65\x3B\x22\x3E","\x20\x20\x20\x20\x3C\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x22\x20\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x22\x6E\x69\x63\x6B\x22\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x6E\x69\x63\x6B\x22\x20\x20\x2F\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x20\x6F\x6E\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x3D\x22\x64\x6F\x4C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x28\x29\x3B\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x66\x61\x6C\x73\x65\x3B\x22\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x6F\x67\x62\x75\x74\x22\x3E\x4C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x20\x20\x3C\x2F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x6F\x67\x62\x75\x74\x6F\x6E\x22\x3E","\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x3E\x4C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x43\x68\x61\x74\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6F\x6E\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3A\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x4F\x6E\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x28\x29\x3B\x22\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x6F\x22\x3E\x4F\x6E\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x55\x73\x65\x72\x73\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x75\x73\x65\x72\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x22\x3E","\x3C\x68\x33\x3E\x4F\x6E\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x55\x73\x65\x72\x73\x3C\x2F\x68\x33\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x75\x73\x65\x72\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72\x22\x3E","\x3C\x75\x6C\x3E\x3C\x6C\x69\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x3E\x43\x6F\x6E\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x75\x6C\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x68\x61\x74\x75\x73\x65\x72\x73\x22\x3E","\x3C\x75\x6C\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x75\x6C\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E"];document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[0]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[2]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[3]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[4]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[5]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[6]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[7]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[8]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[9]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[10]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[11]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[12]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[14]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[15]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[16]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[17]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[18]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[19]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[20]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[21]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[22]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[23]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[24]);document[_0xa338[1]](_0xa338[13]);
```

Thank you for your time. I am trying to use simple stupid techniques to deter the casual coder.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I cannot use server-side logic for it. Please do not advice that.

Comment: Probably not worth the effort.  If you have logic you want to keep private, put it server-side.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not possible to do the same thing server side.

Comment: if there is anything you really need to hide from casual browsers then yes, you probably want to do it server side. For everything else, does it really matter at all? If I was browsing a page source and came across a big chunk of obfuscated text like that, it would make me more curious to try to find out what it was, (a SQL query string? password validation logic?) just for the challenge.

Comment: Fake as in, I know its not some high quality obfuscation. Simply playing with hex values etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Free Javascript Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/)

Does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to use this for easter eggs.. the rest is pretty obfuscated when it goes through Google's Closure compiler... easter eggs, go through that little bit extra.  Though it makes a very small easter egg over 700k.. YMMV.. also you should wrap your obfuscated script in a closure before obfuscating...  ex: (function(b){ ...script here... }(eval('window')));  which will even obfuscate the window reference by name

Comment: example:<pre><code>(function(b,r){

  r.fn.konami = function(callback, code) {/*konami plugin*/.};
  r(b).konami(function(){ alert("Fly with us."); });

 }( 
  eval('window')
  ,eval('jQuery')
 ));</code></pre>

Answer (score 3):

You may try this one [JScrambler](http://jscrambler.com/)

They are accepting sign ups for beta testing I guess

EDIT: It is now out of beta. There are two account models, one is free with only stantard obfuscation, and a paying one with more option for obfuscation among other things.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont mind using another technology, GWT does something similar - except that it will not slow down your script by adding extra indirections.